# How to validate if it's an authorised user sending a request?

Tags: php, validation, authentication

I'm stuck in this situation where I need to validate if it's the right user sending the request/information to the server.  For example, a user submits a delete friend request, in the URL as parameters I include the friend's id (another member id); should I also include the member asking for the friend delete request's id?

I'm just trying to validate or make sure it's the right user sending the request. What's the best way to go about this in general?  If the user is logged in can we just validate by logged in member's id? Or is there a better way?

Comment: If you use the URL to determine who's sending the request, then what's to stop anyone from impersonating another user by changing the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing how your authentication works, it's a little difficult to say.

When I've had to do this in the past, I've used a combination of server-side authentication to identify the user sending the request, and URL parameters to specify what they want to delete. A user needs to be logged in to send a Delete request, and I'm tracking their userID with a $_SESSION variable. So when I get a Delete request, the SQL looks vaguely like:

```
DELETE FROM 
    friends 
WHERE 
    userID=$_SESSION["id"] AND friendID=$_POST["friend"]
```

As halfer explains in the comments, this is a generally bad way of doing things, as it opens an SQL injection vulnerability in the code. You can consider a couple of ways of avoiding that.

Firstly, you can sanitize the data - if you know that your friendID is always going to be an integer, you can check for that. A regular expression to check for non-numeric characters will work - if there's anything dodgy in there, you can deal with it appropriately and not pass it to the database.

The second approach is the one I prefer - when you make your query, you can use a prepared statement, and bind the parameters to it. Using PDO, you'll end up with something that looks like:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM friends WHERE userID=? AND friendID=?');
$sth->bindParam(1, $_SESSION["id"]);
$sth->bindParam(2, $_POST["friend"]);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: exactly, but only thing is when the user sending the request, how do you validate them?  I mean lets say all the user information is sent in the url as parameters, like their memberid,friendid, so should i just check with the memberid sent by the user and see if that matches the session's id?  Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If the user is already logged in, you don't need to send a memberID in the URL - you can take that from $_SESSION. You just need to get the deleteID from the URL, and combine it with the memberID you already have in _SESSION

Comment: oh shiit true...lol...but in general is there a better strategy for authenticating user requests?  a more pro one?

Comment: @halfer - how's that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [session variable](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to store the logged in user id. Once the session is established and your authentication scheme inserts the `logged in` flag you are all set. Just check the `logged in` flag when you need to perform any user requests.

Comment: right, but in terms of user authentication and making sure the right user sent the request, whats teh best strategy?

Comment: Do you have an authentication system in place that checks against the db that a user exists and the credentials are correct? Does it then create a state variable in the `$SESSION` variable indicating that the user is logged in?

Comment: yes i have a membership system in place thats working perfectly fine

Comment: only thing is i want to make sure that the request sent by logged in users are indeed by the right user, makes sense?  basicaly i want to know the best strategy in authenticating logged in user requests if tha makes any sense...

Comment: The session is generated by php and is maintained by the browser. If the user is properly logged in (you have a session variable that says if a user is logged in) then all you need to do is check that that session variable exists and is set as logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Try to require more secure UUID identifiers (generated and stored by you) for such requests, they are still not completely secure but considerably better than simple ids

Comment: so everytime a user sends a request, identify the request by UUID?  so if the UUID for a delete friend request lets say is "12a", when user sends teh request, they have to send "12a" in the paramaters as well right?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. basically you can use short IDs for simple non-secure operations (like get friends of user), BUT you may require the request to delete user's friends will have UUID for both user and each of the friends to be deleted and maybe some extra confirmations too.